# Can I successfully romance Keith David?

Tags: saints-row-iv

My husband and I are playing Saint's Row, and we keep clicking the option to romance Keith David, but he always refuses. Is this some unlockable thing? Is there a quest that lets me romance him?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keith David is the only non-romancable character on the ship, as per the [Saints Wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Keith_David).